# How to make a deeplink to a specific section of iPhone settings on current versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios16

For example, I have an instruction for the user:

1. Go to device settings → "Mobile Data".
2. Click "Network Selection" → turn off the "Automatic" slider.
3. Select the operator

To simplify this instruction, I want to send to user a deeplink directly to the "Network Selection" section. How to do it?

I found these Settings URL schemes: https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/b7019c22fc3152a0b2fe
But they don't work on iOS 16(open only settings).